# How to set default value of start date as yesterday and end date as today in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display default value of start_date and end_date field as yesterday and today respectively.

**Here is my code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#start_date .input-group.date').datepicker({
      startView: 1,
      todayBtn: "linked",
      keyboardNavigation: false,
      forceParse: false,
      autoclose: true,
      format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
      default:today
  });
  $('#end_date .input-group.date').datepicker({
      startView: 1,
      todayBtn: "linked",
      keyboardNavigation: false,
      forceParse: false,
      autoclose: true,
      format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
  });

  $('#published_date .input-group.date').datepicker({
      startView: 1,
      todayBtn: "linked",
      keyboardNavigation: false,
      forceParse: false,
      autoclose: true,
      format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
  });

});
```

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="form-group" id="start_date">
    <label for="">Start Date<span style="color: red;">&nbsp;</span></label>
    <div class="input-group date">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
      <input  type="text" class="form-control" required name="start_date">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="form-group" id="end_date">
    <label for="">End Date<span style="color: red;">&nbsp;</span></label>
    <div class="input-group date">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
      <input  type="text" class="form-control" required name="end_date">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct property for this is [`defaultDate`](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate). It accepts a Date object, a parsable date string, or an integer. I'd suggest using the latter. Use `-1` for yesterday and `0` for today.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#start_date .input-group.date').datepicker({
    startView: 1,
    todayBtn: "linked",
    keyboardNavigation: false,
    forceParse: false,
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    defaultDate: -1
  });
  
  $('#end_date .input-group.date').datepicker({
    startView: 1,
    todayBtn: "linked",
    keyboardNavigation: false,
    forceParse: false,
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    defaultDate: 0
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="form-group" id="start_date">
    <label for="">Start Date<span style="color: red;">&nbsp;</span></label>
    <div class="input-group date">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" required name="start_date">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="form-group" id="end_date">
    <label for="">End Date<span style="color: red;">&nbsp;</span></label>
    <div class="input-group date">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" required name="end_date">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `minDate`

`minDate: -1` for yesterday

`minDate: 0` for today

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#start_date .input-group.date').datepicker({
    startView: 1,
    todayBtn: "linked",
    keyboardNavigation: false,
    forceParse: false,
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    minDate: -1
  });
  $('#end_date .input-group.date').datepicker({
    startView: 1,
    todayBtn: "linked",
    keyboardNavigation: false,
    forceParse: false,
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    minDate:0
  });

  $('#published_date .input-group.date').datepicker({
    startView: 1,
    todayBtn: "linked",
    keyboardNavigation: false,
    forceParse: false,
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="form-group" id="start_date">
    <label for="">Start Date<span style="color: red;">&nbsp;</span></label>
    <div class="input-group date">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" required name="start_date">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="form-group" id="end_date">
    <label for="">End Date<span style="color: red;">&nbsp;</span></label>
    <div class="input-group date">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" required name="end_date">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code example you can assign by deducting days and month or year as well. Please check.

```
 var d = new Date();     
 var currMonth = d.getMonth();
 var currYear = d.getFullYear();    
 var currDate = d.getDate();

 var startDate = new Date(currYear, currMonth, d.getDate());

 var endDate = new Date(currYear, currMonth, currDate - 1);

 $('#start_date').datepicker('setDate', startDate);
 $('#end_date').datepicker('setDate', endDate);
```

Comment: Note that `currDate - 1` will have issues it today is the 1st of the month

Comment: Yes if we deduct the date with this method it is showing minus record or 0 record for first day of month. But with datepicker plugin of JS it is setting up fine for the input tag for date.